# forms toggle with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, toggle

I have a page that shows comments of website audiences from database

End of every comment a form should be display by clicking on a span tag

but it happen only for first comment and i want show the form for all comments

span tag code:

```
<span id="sp2">
    answer
</span>
```

div of form:

```
<div id="rep">
    <form id="repfrm" method="post">
          <label for="rep">Your Answer:</label>
          <textarea name="rep" cols="50" rows="4"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>
</div>
```

my jquery code :

```
$("#sp2").click(function(){
        $("#rep").toggle();
    });
```

Comment: Element ID attribute should be unique per page, i.e. if you have 10 forms on the page, they should all have different ids. You can use class names instead, i.e.: `$(".answer-form").click(...`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `on`:

```
$("body").on("click", "#sp2", function() {
    $("#rep").toggle();
}
```

This reload for itself page elements.

Comment: i use this code but when i click a span all forms will open, i  want only a form open not all of them                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                           $("body").on("click", ".sp2", function() {
     $(".rep").toggle();
    });